# How to send any file from server to client in python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I want to send any file from server to client based on client's request and if file present, then want to send it to client . How should i approach this in python.

Comment: I'd probably use either an FTP setup or a webserver

Comment: What protocol do you need to send it over?

Comment: FTP setup but i want P2P connections